# Generate multiple ErrorListPlots in different colors

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I used the following function in order to plot multiple separate graph. How can I integrate `PlotStyle` in `func` in order to generate each graphic in different color e.g following `"TemperatureMap"`?

```
file = FileNames["*.dat", NotebookDirectory[]];

func[file_String /; FileExistsQ[file]] := 
  Module[{data, formatted}, data = Import[file, "Table"];
   formatted = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#4, #3]} & @@@ data;
   ErrorListPlot[{formatted}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{FileBaseName[file]}], {Right, Bottom}]]];

func /@ file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[func2]; 
func2[file_String /; FileExistsQ[file], color_] := Module[{data, formatted}, 
 data = Import[file, "Table"]; formatted = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#4, #3]} & @@@ data;
 ErrorListPlot[{formatted}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{FileBaseName[file]}], {Right, Bottom}], 
    PlotStyle -> color]]; 
colors = ColorData[ "TemperatureMap"] /@ (Range[Length[file]]/Length[file]); 
func2 @@@ Transpose[{file, colors}]
```